# How to auto-scroll to specific element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I'm creating simple quiz plugin, but now I'm in dilemma, because don't have an idea how to make options to auto-scroll to the top of the **Explanation Box** after visitor choose an answer (right or wrong, explanation box is same with same content. **Note** - explainer box is hidden until visitor clicks with mouse on checkbox of any offered answer.

Below is JavaScript code I have so far:

```js
var wpvqgr = wpvqgr || {};

(function($) 
{
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        wpvqgr.selectAnswer = function($question, question_id, $answer, answer_id)
        {
            // Don't let the user play twice the same question!
            if ($answer.hasClass('wpvqgr-disabled-answer') && !wpvqgr.vars.quiz.settings.trivia_hiderightwrong) {
                return;
            }

            // Right or wrong?
            var rightAnswers    =  wpvqgr.getRightAnswers(question_id);
            var isRight         =  (rightAnswers.indexOf(answer_id) > -1);

            // Store data
            var _answers = wpvqgr.getStore('answers') || { 'questions' : [] };
            _answers.questions[question_id] = { 
                'answer_id'     : answer_id,
                'isRight'       : isRight,
                'rightAnswers'  : rightAnswers,
            };
            wpvqgr.setStore('answers', _answers);

            // Display Right or Wrong answers
            if (wpvqgr.vars.quiz.settings.trivia_hiderightwrong != 'yes')
            {
                // First, disable every answers
                $question.find('.wpvqgr-answer').removeClass('wpvqgr-selected-answer').addClass('wpvqgr-disabled-answer');

                // Add explanation
                var $explanation = $question.find('div.wpvqgr-explanation');
                $explanation.find('div.wpvqgr-explanation-content').html(wpvqgr.vars.quiz.questions[question_id].wpvqgr_quiz_questions_explanation);

                if (isRight) 
                {
                    $explanation.find('h3.wpvqgr-thats-right').show();
                    $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-right-answer');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $explanation.find('h3.wpvqgr-thats-wrong').show();
                    $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-wrong-answer');
                    $.each(rightAnswers, function(index, answer_id){
                        $question.find('.wpvqgr-answer[data-id=' + answer_id + ']').addClass('wpvqgr-right-answer');
                    });
                }

                $explanation.show();
            }
            else
            {
                $question.find('.wpvqgr-answer').removeClass('wpvqgr-selected-answer');
                $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-selected-answer');
            }

            // Update visual checkbox
            $question.find('div.wpvqgr-checkbox-picture').removeClass('wpvqgr-checkbox-checked-picture');
            $answer.find('div.wpvqgr-checkbox-picture').addClass('wpvqgr-checkbox-checked-picture');

            // Not a visual class, just marked as
            $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-is-selected-answer');
        };

        wpvqgr.computeResults = function()
        {
            var answers     =  wpvqgr.getStore('answers') || { 'questions' : [] };
            var finalScore  =  0;

            // Score
            $.each(answers.questions, function (q_id, answer_data) {
                if (answer_data.isRight) {
                    finalScore++;
                }
            });

            // Appreciation
            var appreciation = wpvqgr.getAppreciation(finalScore);

            // Store global data for Facebook, page refresh and other stuff
            wpvqgr.setStore('finalScore', finalScore);
            wpvqgr.setStore('appreciation', appreciation);
        };
        
            //Autoscroll
            
            
            
        /**
         * Integrate results in view
         * @return {[type]} [description]
         */
        wpvqgr.integrateResults = function ()
        {
            wpvqgr.parseResults('quizname', wpvqgr.vars.quiz.general.name);
            wpvqgr.parseResults('score', wpvqgr.getStore('finalScore'));
            wpvqgr.parseResults('total', wpvqgr.getStore('answers').questions.length);
            wpvqgr.parseResults('description', wpvqgr.getStore('appreciation').content);
        }

        wpvqgr.getAppreciation = function(score)
        {
            var finalAppreciationId = -1;
            var finalAppreciationScoreStep = 9999;

            $.each(wpvqgr.vars.quiz.appreciations, function (ap_id, data) 
            {
                var app_score = parseInt(data.score);
                if (score <= app_score && finalAppreciationScoreStep > app_score) 
                {
                    finalAppreciationScoreStep  =  app_score;
                    finalAppreciationId         =  ap_id;
                }
            });

            // No appreciation found!
            if (finalAppreciationId == -1) {
                return { 'content':'', 'redirect':'', 'picture':'', 'score':-1 }
            } else {
                return wpvqgr.vars.quiz.appreciations[finalAppreciationId];
            }
        };

        wpvqgr.getRightAnswers = function(question_id)
        {
            var rightAnswers = [];

            var answers = wpvqgr.vars.quiz.questions[question_id]['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers'];
            $.each(answers, function(id, data) {
                if (data['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers_right']) {
                    rightAnswers.push(id);
                }
            });

            return rightAnswers;
        };

        wpvqgr.getFinalScore = function()
        {
            return wpvqgr.getStore('finalScore');
        };
    });

})(jQuery);

/**
 * Store
 *
 * questions[$id] = $answer_id
 *
 *
 * 
 */
```

```html
<?php global $wpvqgr_quiz, $wpvqgr_quiz_columns, $wpvqgr_resources_dir_url, $wpvqgr_skin_dir_url; ?>

<!-- Load CSS Skin Theme -->
<style> @import url('<?php echo $wpvqgr_resources_dir_url . 'css/bootstrap-wrapper.css'; ?>'); </style>
<style> @import url('<?php echo $wpvqgr_resources_dir_url . 'icons/fa/css/font-awesome.min.css'; ?>'); </style>
<style> @import url('<?php echo $wpvqgr_resources_dir_url . 'css/fo-style.css'; ?>'); </style>
<style> @import url('<?php echo $wpvqgr_skin_dir_url . 'style.css'; ?>'); </style>

<!-- Custom style -->
<style>
    <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('progessbarcolor') != ''): ?>
        .wpvqgr-wrapper button.wpvqgr-button.wpvqgr-playagain,
        .wpvqgr-wrapper button.wpvqgr-button.wpvqgr-start-button,
        .wpvqgr-wrapper div.wpvqgr-continue button.wpvqgr-button,
        .wpvqgr-wrapper button.wpvqgr-button.wpvqgr-askinfo-submit,
        .wpvqgr-progress .progress-bar {
            background-color:<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('progessbarcolor'); ?>;
        }
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_custom_css'); ?>
</style>

<!-- Facebook SDK -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<!-- / Prepare sharing options -->
    
<?php echo apply_filters('wpvqgr_public_version', "<!--  Quiz Created with WP Viral Quiz (v".WPVQGR_VERSION.") - https://www.ohmyquiz.io/discover -->"); ?>

<a name="wpvqgr"></a>

<div class="wpvqgr-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('startbutton') && !$wpvqgr_resultsOnly): ?>
            <div class="wpvqgr-intro">
                <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('startbuttonintro')): ?>
                    <p><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('startbuttonintro'); ?></p>
                <?php endif ?>
                <button class="wpvqgr-start-button wpvqgr-button"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_startbutton'); ?></button>
            </div>
        <?php endif ?>

        <div id="wpvqgr-<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getId(); ?>" class="wpvqgr <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getType(); ?>">

            <div class="wpvqgr-a-d-s">
                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_before')); ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('ads_before')); ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getPageCounter() > 1 && in_array('top', $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('progessbar'))): ?>
                <!-- Progress bar -->
                <div class="wpvqgr-progress wpvqgr-progress-top progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if (!$wpvqgr_resultsOnly): ?>
                <a href="" id="wpvqgrquestion"></a>
                <div class="wpvqgr-page-0 wpvqgr-page" data-id="0">

                    <?php   
                        $wpvqgr_questions = $wpvqgr_quiz->getQuestionsAndBlocks();
                        $q_real_id = -1;
                        foreach($wpvqgr_questions as $q_id => $question):

                            // Type and content
                            $q_type             =  $question['_type'];
                            $q_content          =  ($q_type == 'wpvqgr_quiz_htmlblocks') ? $question['wpvqgr_quiz_htmlblocks_content'] : $question['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_content'];

                            // Real ID (ignore HTML blocks)
                            if ($q_type == 'wpvqgr_quiz_questions') {
                                $q_real_id++;
                            }

                            // Pagination
                            $q_isTherePage      =  ($question['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_addpage'] && isset($wpvqgr_questions[$q_id+1]));
                            $currentPage_id     =  (!isset($currentPage_id)) ? 0 : $currentPage_id;

                            // Picture
                            if ($q_type == 'wpvqgr_quiz_questions') {
                                $q_picture_id       =  $question['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_picture'];
                                $q_picture_info     =  WPVQGR_Snippets::wpGetAttachment($q_picture_id);
                                $q_picture_url      =  wp_get_attachment_url($q_picture_id);
                            }
                    ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <!-- Global ads between questions -->
                                <?php if ( $q_real_id > 0 && $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_between_count') > 0 && ($q_real_id % $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_between_count') == 0) ): ?>
                                    <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_between_content'); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                
                                <!-- HTML Blocks -->
                                <?php if ($q_type == 'wpvqgr_quiz_htmlblocks'): ?>
                                    <div class="wpvqgr-htmlblock">
                                        <?php echo do_shortcode($q_content); ?>
                                    </div>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                <!-- Regular question -->
                                
                                    <div class="wpvqgr-question" data-id="<?php echo $q_real_id; ?>">
                                        <div class="wpvqgr-question-label"><?php echo do_shortcode(nl2br($q_content)); ?></div>
                                        
                                        <?php if (is_numeric($q_picture_id)): ?>
                                            <div class="wpvqgr-question-picture">
                                                <figure class="figure">
                                                    <img src="<?php echo $q_picture_url; ?>" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="<?php echo htmlentities($q_picture_info['alt']); ?>" />
                                                    <?php if ($q_picture_info['caption'] != ''): ?>
                                                        <figcaption class="figure-caption"><?php echo $q_picture_info['caption']; ?></figcaption>
                                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                                </figure>
                                                <?php if (function_exists ('adinserter')) echo adinserter (1); ?> <!-- / First Add Code -->
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif ?>
                                
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <?php 
                                                $smartColumns = WPVQGR_Snippets::getSmartColumnsSize($question, $wpvqgr_quiz_columns);
                                                foreach ($question['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers'] as $a_id => $answer):
                                                    // Answer
                                                    $a_label            =  $answer['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers_answer'];

                                                    // Picture
                                                    if ($smartColumns['displayPicture'])
                                                    {
                                                        $a_picture_id    =  $answer['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers_picture'];
                                                        if ($a_picture_id == 0) {
                                                            $a_picture_info  =  array('alt' => '', 'caption' => '');
                                                            $a_picture_url   =  WPVQGR_PLUGIN_URL . '/resources/images/picture-placeholder.jpg';
                                                        } else {
                                                            $a_picture_info  =  WPVQGR_Snippets::wpGetAttachment($a_picture_id);
                                                            $a_picture_url   =  wp_get_attachment_image_src($a_picture_id, 'wpvqgr-square-answer');
                                                            $a_picture_url   =  $a_picture_url[0];
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                            ?>
                                                    <div class="wpvqgr-answer-col col-xs-<?php echo $smartColumns['xs-size']; ?> col-md-<?php echo $smartColumns['md-size']; ?>">
                                                        <div class="wpvqgr-answer" data-id="<?php echo $a_id; ?>">

                                                            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getType() == 'wpvqgr_quiz_perso'): ?>
                                                                <!-- Multipliers -->
                                                                <?php foreach ($answer['wpvqgr_quiz_questions_answers_multipliers'] as $p_id => $value): ?>
                                                                    <input type="hidden" name="wpvqgr_answer_multipliers[]" data-pid="<?php echo (int)$p_id; ?>" value="<?php echo (int)$value; ?>" />
                                                                <?php endforeach ?>
                                                            <?php endif; ?>

                                                            <?php if ($smartColumns['displayPicture']): ?>
                                                                <div class="wpvqgr-answer-picture">
                                                                    <figure class="figure">
                                                                        <img src="<?php echo $a_picture_url; ?>" class="figure-img img-fluid" alt="<?php echo htmlentities($a_picture_info['alt']); ?>" />
                                                                        <?php if ($a_picture_info['caption'] != ''): ?>
                                                                            <figcaption class="figure-caption"><?php echo $a_picture_info['caption']; ?></figcaption>
                                                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                                                    </figure>
                                                                </div>
                                                            <?php endif ?>
                                                            
                                                            <?php if ($a_label != ''): ?>
                                                                <div class="wpvqgr-checkbox">
                                                                    <div class="wpvqgr-checkbox-picture wpvqgr-checkbox-unchecked-picture"></div>
                                                                    <span class="wpvqgr-answer-label"><?php echo do_shortcode(stripslashes($a_label)); ?></span>
                                                                    <hr class="wpvqgr-clear" />
                                                                </div>
                                                            <?php endif ?>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="wpvqgr-explanation">
                                                    <center><h6>⇩ SCROLL DOWN TO CONTINUE ⇩</h6></center>
                                                    <h3 class="wpvqgr-thats-right"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_right'); ?></h3>
                                                    <h3 class="wpvqgr-thats-wrong"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_wrong'); ?></h3>
                                                    <div class="wpvqgr-explanation-content"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div> <!-- .question -->
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div> <!-- / col -->
                        </div> <!-- / row -->
                        <div class="autoscroll>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="wpvqgr-continue">
                            <?php if (function_exists ('adinserter')) echo adinserter (2); ?> <!-- / Second Add Code -->
                            <button class="wpvqgr-button" style="background:<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('progessbarcolor'); ?>;">
                                <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_continuebutton'); ?>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    
                        <?php 
                            if ($q_isTherePage): $currentPage_id++; 
                        ?>
                            </div> <!-- close previous page -->
                            <div class="wpvqgr-page-<?php echo $currentPage_id; ?> wpvqgr-page" data-id="<?php echo $currentPage_id; ?>">
                        <?php endif ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div> <!-- Final page close -->
            <?php endif; ?>

            <a id="wpvqgr-resultarea"></a>

            <!-- Force to share -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <div class="wpvqgr-forcetoshare">
                        <h3><?php echo __("Share the quiz to show your results !", 'wpvq'); ?></h3>
                        <button class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-social-facebook wpvqgr-force-share" data-title="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_facebook_title'); ?>" data-description="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_facebook_description'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo __('Share on Facebook', 'wpvq'); ?></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Force to give some informations -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 offset-md-1">
                    <div class="wpvqgr-askinfo">
                        <h3><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_askinfotitle'); ?></h3>
                        <form action="" method="GET">
                            <?php foreach($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('askinfo_fields') as $field): ?>
                                <?php 
                                    $field_slug         =  WPVQGR_Snippets::slugify($field['wpvqgr_settings_askinfo_fields_field_label']); 
                                    $is_required_field  =  ($field['wpvqgr_settings_askinfo_fields_field_optional'] != 'yes');
                                ?>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="wpvqgr-<?php echo $field_slug; ?>"><?php echo $field['wpvqgr_settings_askinfo_fields_field_label']; ?></label>
                                    <input type="<?php echo $field['wpvqgr_settings_askinfo_fields_field_type']; ?>" class="form-control" name="<?php echo $field_slug; ?>" id="wpvqgr-<?php echo $field_slug; ?>" <?php if($is_required_field): ?>required="true"<?php endif; ?>/>
                                </div>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>

                            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_gdpr_enabled') == 1): ?>
                                <div class="form-check gdpr-area">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="wpvq_gpdr" id="wpvq_gpdr_checkbox" required="true" />
                                        <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_gdpr_message'); ?>
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif ?>

                            <div class="form-group" style="text-align:center;">
                                <button type="submit" class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-askinfo-submit"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_askinfobutton'); ?></button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        
                        <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('askinfo_ignore')): ?>
                            <p class="wpvqgr-askinfo-ignore"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_askinfoignore'); ?></p>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Show results -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="wpvqgr-results">

                        <div class="wpvqgr-a-d-s">
                            <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_aboveresults')); ?>
                            <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('ads_aboveresults')); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wpvqgr-results-box <?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getType(); ?>">
                        
                            <div class="wpvqgr-top-result">
                                <div class="wpvqgr-quiz-name"><?php echo stripslashes($wpvqgr_quiz->getName()); ?></div>
                                <h3><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_result'); ?></h3>
                                <div class="wpvqgr-result-description">%%description%%</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wpvqgr-additional-results">
                                <div class="wpvqgr-additional-results-template">
                                    <h3><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_additional_results'); ?></h3>
                                    <div class="wpvqgr-result-description">%%description%%</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="wpvqgr-a-d-s">
                                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_afterresults')); ?>
                                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('ads_afterresults')); ?>
                            </div>

                            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('displaysharing')): ?>
                                <div class="wpvqgr-sharing">
                                    <?php if (!in_array('facebook', $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_socialmedia_hide'))): ?>
                                        <button class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-social-facebook" data-title="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_facebook_title'); ?>" data-description="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_facebook_description'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo __('Share on Facebook', 'wpvq'); ?></button>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                     
                                    <!-- Twitter -->
                                    <?php if (!in_array('twitter', $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_socialmedia_hide'))): ?>
                                        <button class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-social-twitter" data-tweet="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_twitter'); ?>" data-mention="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('twittermention'); ?>" data-hashtag="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('twitterhashtag'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo __('Share on Twitter', 'wpvq'); ?></button>
                                    <?php endif ?>

                                    <!-- VK -->
                                    <?php if (!in_array('vk', $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_socialmedia_hide'))): ?>
                                        <button class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-social-vk" data-title="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_vk_title'); ?>" data-description="<?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_template_vk_description'); ?>"><i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; <?php echo __('Share on VK', 'wpvq'); ?></button>
                                    <?php endif ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('playagain')): ?>
                            <button class="wpvqgr-button wpvqgr-playagain"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_playagainbutton'); ?></button>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getPageCounter() > 1 && in_array('bottom', $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('progessbar'))): ?>
                <!-- Progress bar -->
                <div class="wpvqgr-progress wpvqgr-progress-bottom progress">
                    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif ?>

            <div class="wpvqgr-a-d-s">
                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('global_ads_after')); ?>
                <?php echo do_shortcode($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('ads_after')); ?>
            </div>

            <?php if ($wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('promote')): ?>
                <div class="wpvqgr-promote">
                    <p>
                        <?php _e("This quiz has been created with", 'wpvq'); ?> <a href="https://www.ohmyquiz.io/discover" target="_blank">WordPress Viral Quiz</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div> <!-- / #wpvqgr -->
    </div> <!-- / container -->

    <!-- Loading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="wpvqgr-loader">
            <p>
                <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
                <span class="sr-only"><?php _e("Loading...", 'wpvq'); ?></span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- / Bootstrap wrapper -->
```

I tried with dummy DIV element, but without success (to have it as an anchor, because explainer element is invisible).

Code samples I tried so far are:

```
$('wpvqgr-answer').click(function() {
         $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: ('#autoscroll').offset().top - staticHeaderHeight}, 'slow');
         return true;
         });
```

And:

```
$('.wpvqgr-answer').click(function () {
         $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(el).closest(':visible').offset().top}, 400);
         return true;
        });
```

And, this was desperate act of self destruction:

```
 $('.wpvqgr-answer').click(() => {
      $('.wpvqgr-explanation').toggle('smooth', () => {
      $('.wpvqgr-explanation').get(0).scrollIntoView();
       });
   });
```

I hope you have some kind of overview now, even in basic sense. Any guidance appreciated. Thank you

**EDIT:** Box creation conditions are within JS and parsed to HTML code, example below:

```js
// Add explanation
                var $explanation = $question.find('div.wpvqgr-explanation');
                $explanation.find('div.wpvqgr-explanation-content').html(wpvqgr.vars.quiz.questions[question_id].wpvqgr_quiz_questions_explanation);

                if (isRight) 
                {
                    $explanation.find('h3.wpvqgr-thats-right').show();
                    $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-right-answer');
                } 
                else 
                {
                    $explanation.find('h3.wpvqgr-thats-wrong').show();
                    $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-wrong-answer');
                    $.each(rightAnswers, function(index, answer_id){
                        $question.find('.wpvqgr-answer[data-id=' + answer_id + ']').addClass('wpvqgr-right-answer');
                    });
                }

                $explanation.show();
            }
            else
            {
                $question.find('.wpvqgr-answer').removeClass('wpvqgr-selected-answer');
                $answer.addClass('wpvqgr-selected-answer');
            }
```

```html
 <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="wpvqgr-explanation">
                                                    <center><h6>⇩ SCROLL DOWN TO CONTINUE ⇩</h6></center>
                                                    <h3 class="wpvqgr-thats-right"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_right'); ?></h3>
                                                    <h3 class="wpvqgr-thats-wrong"><?php echo $wpvqgr_quiz->getSetting('customlabel_wrong'); ?></h3>
                                                    <div class="wpvqgr-explanation-content"></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Is the explanation box created with JS or is it already present in the HTML?

Comment: @MeltingDog you can find explanation and code in EDIT section of question

Answer (score 0):

Simple piece of code worked as charm for me, just enough to achieve functionality and in the same time not to complicate too much:

```
const goToTop = () => window.scrollTo(0, 950);
            goToTop();
```

This is very quick and "clean" solution for one who does not need complicated function.